# Hartshorne's proof of Proposition 2.5, Chapter II of his book Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $S = \sum_{n\ge 0} S_n$ be a graded commutative ring.
Let $f$ be a homogeneous element of $S$ of degree $> 0$.
Let $D_+(f) = \{\mathfrak{p} \in\operatorname{Proj} S\mid f \notin \mathfrak{p}\}$.
Let $S_{(f)}$ be the degree $0$ part of the graded ring $S_f$, where $S_f$ is the localization with respect to the multiplicative set $\{1, f, f^2,\dots\}$.
The proposition states that

> $D_+(f)$ is isomorphic to Spec $S_{(f)}$ as locally ringed spaces.

Part of his proof is as follows.
For $\mathfrak{p} \in D_+(f)$, let $\psi(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{p}S_f\cap S_{(f)}$.
Then $\psi(\mathfrak{p}) \in$ Spec $S_{(f)}$.
He wrote that the properties of localization show that $\psi\colon D_+(f) \rightarrow$ Spec $S_{(f)}$ is bijective.
I wonder why $\psi$ is surjective.

Comment: Given $\mathfrak{p}_0\in\mathrm{Spec}(S_{(f)})$, the ideal $\mathfrak{p}_0S_f$ of $S_f$ is homogeneous, and its radical $\sqrt{\mathfrak{p}_0S_f}$ is homogeneous and prime, so of the form $\mathfrak{q}S_f$ for a homogeneous prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $S$ with $f\notin\mathfrak{q}$. It can be verified that this $\mathfrak{q}$ maps to $\mathfrak{p}_0$ under $\psi$.

Answer (score 3):

This is taken from Iitaka's "Algebraic Geometry", Lemma 3.1(3):

Let $d=\text{deg}(f)$. Given $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}\left(S_{(f)}\right)$, we define $I_m$ to be $\{b\in S_m\mid b^d/f^m\in \mathfrak{p}\}$. It can be checked that $I_m$ is an abelian group, that $I:=\oplus I_m$ is a homogeneous prime ideal of $S$ not containing $f$, and that $\psi(I)=\mathfrak{p}$.